# Is there a way to define new HTML elements without document.registerElement()?

Tags: javascript, html, api

In some browsers you can define new HTML elements with custom functionality and so on using the really uncompatible `Document.registerElement()` API. Is there a way to avoid using this API and create new HTML elements compatible with many browsers?

Comment: That method is deprecated. Consider looking at Polymer for polyfills of this functionality.

Comment: @NathanMontez Thanks! Polymer looks like the bib I was lookink for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh, yes. Using the **[DOM standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)**:

```
document.createElement("element type")
```

You can (but I don't know why you would) use this to create non-standard elements. After that, they are just JavaScript objects, so you can customize them as you would any other object.

> In an HTML document, the Document.createElement() method creates the
>   HTML element specified by tagName, or an **[HTMLUnknownElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement)** if tagName
>   isn't recognized.

```js
// Causes an HTMLUnknownElement to be created
var e = document.createElement("custom");

// Supports basic element interface
e.innerHTML = "I'm in a new &lt;custom&gt; element.";

// But, is a JS object like any other and so customized
// as such:
e.custom = function(){
  alert("custom operation");
};

// Is an element node (although invalid), so can be inserted into the DOM
document.body.appendChild(e);

// But, has custom functions:
e.custom();
```

Comment: Well, I know that, but the question is, if I can add custom functionality and methods to the element...

Comment: I think the question is "how to register *new* (aka non standard) elements" ... however, I don't really see why you would do this in practice.

Comment: @AntonBallmaier You can (but I don't know why you would) use this to create non-standard elements. After that, they are just JavaScript objects, so you can customize them as you would any other object.

Comment: @Damon You can do this with `document.createElement()`.

Comment: Yes very true, +1. Personally dislike this pattern but looks like OP found Polymer which should be suitable to their needs.

Answer (score 1):

Document.registerElement is deprecated now. Try this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define

Comment: The browser compatibility seems to be even worse for `CustomElementRegistry.define()` :/